# How to send report/story by e-mail in SAP Analytics Cloud

Tags: sap-cloud-foundry, sap-analytics-cloud

We are using SAP Analytics Cloud and since many users didn't have a license, we simply used to published the Stories and send them to their email address by providing their office email addresses in the non-SAP Analytics Cloud Recipients text box while in the Publish window.

These users now have their own licenses and we can now send them the reports (stories) so they can receive an alert in SAC and directly view the stories in SAP Analytics, but now we are unable to also send the stories to their office email addresses.

We are also now using SAP Cloud Foundry so could that be related?

Answer (score 0):

All good now. After trying once again it worked. Thanks.